# ASP.net javascript fire on asp:ImageButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hey all i am trying to figure out why i am getting this error when my page loads:

```
 Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'showNotifier' is not a member of 'ASP.pro_aspx'.
```

showNotifier is a javascript call that i have to display a error message that drops down from the top of the browser screen using jQuery. I have the javascript code loading up in my master page so i know its there on any page.

Here is my imagebutton code:

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' Text="Delete" runat="server" CssClass="delIcon" AlternateText="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" ImageUrl="~/del.png" />
```

Any help would be great!

**Additional code**

```
Protected Sub grdView_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grdView.RowCommand
    Dim cid As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString
    Dim command As String = e.CommandName.ToString

    If cid.Length <= 0 Then Exit Sub

    Select Case command
        Case "Delete"
            Delete(cid)
    End Select
End Sub
```

**Additional code 2**

```
Private Sub grdView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdView.RowDataBound
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
        Dim l As ImageButton = CType(e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete"), ImageButton)

        l.Attributes("OnClientClick") = "if(msgBoxShow('Are you sure you want to delete " & DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name") & "?','" & DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name") & "','')==false){return false;}"
    End If
End Sub
```

Javascript code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function msgBoxShow(boxsaying, prodItemName, codeBehind) {
    apprise(boxsaying, {
        'verify': true,
        'textYes': 'Delete ' + prodItemName,
        'textNo': 'Cancel delete'
    },
                function (r) {
                    if (r) {
                        //alert('yes');
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        //alert('no');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
           );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Still having problems with this. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

`OnClick` in an `<asp:ImageButton>` is used to identify the function in the code-behind that will run when you click and the page is posted-back to the server (this is the same as for a normal `<asp:Button>`)

What you mean is `OnClientClick` which will run javascript on the client

---

**Update** due to comment from OP

In order to only return if your local javascript function returns false would be to do the following...

```
OnClientClick="if(myFn()==false){return false;}"
```

What this means is that when the function returns `false` it will cancel the clicking of the button, meaning the form will not be posted (this will **also** result in any client side validation not being run, should there be any).

If the function returns `true` then it will carry on through and do the post-back to your server.

In regards to calling the correct function on the server, I would create a function specifically for the image button, such as...

```
Protected Sub imgBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   ...
End Sub
```

Then you want to have `OnClick="imgBtn_Click"`

Comment: How would i call the javascript and if its **yes** then call the code behind which would be **Protected Sub grdView_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grdView.RowCommand**?

Comment: I've added the code above for the click even in the code-behind.

Comment: Apologies @Stealth, I've been away from my computer.  I will update my answer to show you how I'd do it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my OP as it has a loop that it populates the asp button. The current code works and displays the alert as a test but it goes right to the **Delete** part of the **grdView_RowCommand** after clicking on the OK button in the alert. How do i prevent it to do so if its "false"?

Comment: @Stealth, did you read my answer? In particular the part about how to stop the post-back if the function returns false?

Comment: Sure i did, freefaller. If you see my javascript code i do have "return false" in it.. But it still fires off the **grdView_RowCommand**

Comment: OK, so you read it and then ignored it. What I was saying was the you must deal the **return value of the function in the `OnClientClick` handler**.  Returning a value from a function means nothing if you don't actually do something on the otherside

Comment: @Stealth, update your code to this in `grdView_RowDataBound`... `l.Attributes("onclick") = "if(testing()==false){return false;}"`

Comment: you could also just simplify `if(testing()==false) { return false; }` to `return testing();`

Comment: Only, @Mike, if you don't have client-side validation

Comment: @freefaller: i added that to my code and i get **Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'msgBoxShow' is undefined** when i click on it. And again, i have the msgBoxShow inside the master page so i know its there. I've also tested it out just using a normal link and it works just fine to show the messagebox.

Comment: @Stealth, this is **way** outside the scope of your original question.  `msgBoxShow` is not javascript, and it's not even valid in VBScript... it would be `msgBox.show`. Are you sure you don't mean `alert()`?

Comment: @freefaller: I forgot to move the **msgBoxShow** into the master page. Its there now and no errors but it still fires off the **grdView_RowCommand** before i answer yes or no. **Check out the OP for the updated code**

Comment: @Stealth, I have no knowledge of `apprise` (is it jquery?), but you are not returning any value from `msgBoxShow`.  I really have very little time left to spend with you sorry

Comment: apprise is this > http://thrivingkings.com/read/Apprise-The-attractive-alert-alternative-for-jQuery

Comment: @freefaller: After returning true or false i still get the error of **The GridView 'grdView' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled. ** from the grdView_RowCommand being fired.

Comment: Sorry @Stealth, I'm not going to help you anymore... you're dealing (according to the website) with a piece of code that is no longer supported.  I have hopefully given you a direction to go in, but I simply have no more time to spend with you. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

onClick attributes to elements (especially if being on hundreds of elements on a page) are actually an old way of doing things. Especially if you care about older browsers (and IE6-8), these create "script" blocks (each one individually) for each one of the elements that all basically call the same thing, and are the same type of element. These slow down the page tremendously in older browsers, I highly advise never using them.

It is much better to simply create an overall live event handler on all of these items like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delIcon', function () {
    showNotifier(3000,'#cf5050','Delete this?');
});
```

This will create one event waiting for all of these items (with the class of delIcon). I'm assuming it would solve your problem as well. ASP.NET is assuming that showNotifier is a back-end method.

Comment: How would i call the javascript and if its **yes** then call the code behind which would be **Protected Sub grdView_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grdView.RowCommand**?

Comment: I've added the code above for the click even in the code-behind.

Comment: Well you'd either have to make that method an AJAX method or call it with __doPostBack('grdView_RowCommand', 'Arguments Here'); http://asimsajjad.blogspot.com/2009/04/calling-dopostback-in-our-own.html, can google about __doPostBack, plenty of info on it!

Answer (score 1):

In your `ImageButton`, `OnClick` is meant to reference an event handler in your code-behind, not client-side script.  You should be using `OnClientClick` instead.